# is message[0] is final in message array

Tags: java, final

I was getting `Cannot refer to a non-final variable message inside an inner class defined in a different method` for my following onMessage method.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message msg) {

    if (msg instanceof ActiveMQMessage){
        try {
             ActiveMQMessage aMsg =  (ActiveMQMessage)msg;

             String message = ""; // I cant use final here because my if else message assingment
                int consumerCount =(Integer) aMsg.getProperty("consumerCount");

                if(consumerCount == 0 ){
                    message = "No cousumers for queue bank.7083 (HNB Bank)";
                }else{
                    message = "Added new consumer to bank.7083 (HNB Bank) total counsumers : "+consumerCount;
                }


                final MessageCreator request = new MessageCreator() {

                    public Message createMessage(final Session session) throws JMSException {
                        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
                        textMessage.setText(message); // I’m getting compilation issue here
                        return textMessage;
                    }
                };

                amqTemplate.send("HUTCH", request);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Then I used `String [] messages = new String[1]` array instead of my `String message` and changed my code like bellow.

```
.
.
.
                final String[]  message = new String[1];
if(consumerCount == 0 ){
                    message[0] = "No cousumers for queue bank.7083 (HNB Bank)";
                }else{
                    message[0] = "Added new consumer to bank.7083 (HNB Bank) total counsumers : "+consumerCount;
                }

.
.
.
textMessage.setText(message[0]);
```

And it was compile without any issue. In my Understanding message[0] is not final. That is why I was able to assign different messages for message[0]. Also though message array is final setText method is asking a string not a array. I think I have missed something here and which will prevent me to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

No, you haven't missed anything. Only `message` has to be `final`; `message[0]` doesn't and isn't.

Comment: problem is when i used final in message in my if else statement again I get compilation error. because I cant change value when it is final.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction on accessing non-`final` things in an inner class only applies to **local variables**.

There is nothing wrong with accessing non-`final` fields or array elements on instances that you have access to.